# PHP shortcut for addition with array index that may or may not exist?

Tags: php

This feels incredibly basic, but I think I'm missing a trick.  Suppose I have this:

```
$array[$key] += $value;
```

Works fine if $array[$key] is already set, but PHP Notice Undefined variable if it isn't.

Obviously I can do

```
if (isset($array[$key]))
    $array[$key] += $value;
else
    $array[$key] = $value;
```

or

```
$array[$key] = (isset($array[$key])) ? $array[$key] + $value : $value;
```

But I feel there's probably something neater?

Comment: No, you have to live with that.

Comment: Correct, if there is no value already set to an array item, you can't add anything to it. It's like dividing by 0.

Comment: I understand that @the_pete, I just wondered if there was a clever syntax trick I was missing out on.  Something along the lines of (but not) $array[$key] = $array[$key] + $value || $value;  I guess there would be @ options too.

Comment: Well if you are looking for syntactical shortcuts, you can look into the `if then else...` [short hand](http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Comment: I already included a ternary option in my original post, but thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, even though the first one will rightly give a notice, it should still work.

Comment: It does indeed work, but occasionally I peruse my error_log file and see do my best to clean up anything that's occurring in there.

Answer (score 0):

instead of isset($array[$foo]), use !empty($array[$foo]) to process existing values and the else handles non-existent index.

Answer (score 0):

In the situations when you know what the full set of `$key` values looks like prior to summing, then you can prepare the array ahead of time and use just `+=`

```
$array = array_fill_keys($all_keys, 0);
```

Avoiding an if/then inside of a loop is a good thing.